# Bluetooth Firmware rtl8821a_fw.bin Fails to Load in Debian

Tags: debian, bluetooth, firmware

I am using Debian 9.4 on Lenovo IdeaPad 110. In the opening screen, I get these messages;

```
[12...] rt18821ae 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rt18821aefw.bin (-2)
[12...] rt18821ae 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rt18821aefw.wowlan.bin
[12...] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load rtl_bt/rtl18821a_config.bin (-2)
[12...] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rt18821a_config.bin
[12...] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load rtl_bt/rtl18821a_fw.bin (-2)
[12...] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rt18821a_fw.bin
[23...] r8169 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw (-2)
```

and when I write `dmesg | grep firmware` I get following message;

```
[   11.605280] rtl8821ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
[   11.605290] rtl8821ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin
[   11.630704] rtl8821ae 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load
rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin (-2)
[   11.630712] rtl8821ae 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for
rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin failed with error -2
[   11.642658] rtl8821ae 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware
rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
[   12.685508] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load
rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin (-2)
[   12.685511] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for
rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin failed with error -2
[   12.685526] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load
rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin (-2)
[   12.685527] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for
rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin failed with error -2
[   23.375275] r8169 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware
rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw
```

So basically, my computer fails to load
three files;

- rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin
- rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
- rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin

I added non-free sources to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and install firmware-realtek with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

`rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin` can be located in `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt/` and `rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin` can be located
in `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/` . But still I get these errors and my bluetooth is not working, but Wi-Fi is working. Anybody have an idea, how to fix this?

edit: kernel version: `4.9.0-6-amd64` and the output of `apt-cache policy firmware-realtek` is;

```
firmware-realtek:
  Installed: 20161130-3
  Candidate: 20161130-3
  Version table:
 *** 20161130-3 500
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.43 500
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie/non-free amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie/non-free i386 Packages
```

But after several times of rebooting again, now somehow the bluetooth works. Even the `config` file is still missing and I got errors at the start. My primary use for the bluetooth is for sound and when I connect the bluetooth speakers the sounds is very distorted and comes from deep. I do not yet know, if this is about the missing `config` file, which I expect not to. Anyway I will check this as solved, even though I quite not clear about all process.

Comment: What kernel are you running?

Comment: it is in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your wifi works is that `rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin`is properly loaded. IIRC there are also *optional* firmware files and when these are missing, the error message is `Direct firmware load for {name} failed with error %d`. Because this is misleading, the kernel developers agreed in May 2018 that they should add a new call `firmware_request_nowarn()` that will not throw those messages.

The package `firmware-realtek` contains the files that you're missing. Please add the output of `apt-cache policy firmware-realtek` to your question.

Comment: @rctus Did you found  the `bt/rtl8821a_config.bin`? Is not in the realtek package. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

rtl8821a firmware is not shipped with Linux distribution if you see error below errors:

```
Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin failed with error -2
firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin not found
```

Execute below commands to install firmware.

```
cd /tmp
# Download rtl8821a_config and rtl8821a_fw from https://github.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek/rtk1395/bt/rtkbt/Firmware/BT/rtl8821a_config
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek/rtk1395/bt/rtkbt/Firmware/BT/rtl8821a_fw
mv rtl8821a_config /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
mv rtl8821a_fw /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
hciconfig -a # will show that Bluetooth is up now
```

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
> bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin failed with error -2
```

Realtek does not provide the config for "rtl8821a_config", you can symlink with rtl8723d_config.

Check if the file with failure lists here:

```
> ls /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/
```

If not, make a symlink to other firmware config with the same name of the file missing:

```
> sudo ln -s /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin.xz /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin.xz
```

Reboot and check if it solves.

```
> dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    3.604451] usb 1-1.2: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    9.455922] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.455991] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.455998] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.456001] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.456016] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.673364] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.673366] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.673370] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.820652] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000a lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8821
[    9.821622] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    9.821623] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
[    9.828456] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
[    9.830156] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 17438
[   10.263579] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e2fa041
[   39.206147] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   39.206155] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   39.206162] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

All working!
(openSUSE Tumbleweed)